# Should women stay up Shavuos night?

Tags: women, shavuos, evening-night, sleep

Should females remain awake the night of Shavuos? (sources please)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Yeshiva.org here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=1436) (under heading תיקון ליל שבועות, number 15 [טו]):

> לימוד נשים - נשים אינן חייבות בתיקון ליל שבועות, ואם הן באות ולומדות תנ"ך וכד' תבוא עליהן ברכה (שו"ת רב פעלים א, או"ח סוד ישרים, סי' ט).

And [here](http://www.bknw.org/library/articles/yom-tov/Laws%20and%20Customs%20of%20Shavuos.pdf) (second paragraph under heading "staying up at night")

> Responsa  Rav Pa’alim  (Sod Yesharim 9) points out that for mystical reasons women who wish to stay up on the night of Shavuot should not recite the tikun

Which both quote from Rav Pa'alim that women should not read Tikkun Leil Shavuos, but staying up is a good thing (although optional).

Looking around online, I see some people say women in their community do stay up, and some say they don't.

Answer (score 1):

As brought on this website:
http://www.atorahminute.com/2014-06-01
The Ben Ish Chai said that women should NOT stay up on the night of Shavuos for Kabbalistic reasons.

Comment: Ben Is Chai is cited in the other answer as just saying they shouldn't say the formal kabbalistic Tikkun. Your site may be misrepresenting this.